# Loading the DataGrid with partial response while still downloading in get request

Tags: c#, wpf, httprequest, httpclient, httpresponse

I have a HttpClient that is trying to Get huge amount of json data from the WebAPI. Then load these data into a DataGrid.

I have tried to implement the **HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead** , so that I dont wait for it to load entire response. But I am not too sure what is the best way to utilize this for my use case scenario here.

Is there any possible way to partially reading the stream and deserialize them, then fill it with the DataGrid while the GetRequest is still ongoing?

Or my only option are fully wait for GetRequest operation to be fully completed, then deserialize them into object and use them as the DataSource of the DataGrid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you could feed the DataGrid gradually if that WebAPI endpoint supports pagination.
If it's yours you could try to implement it.